Unlevel Floor Problem
There is a dip in my kitchen/dining room floor. It is about 3/4 of an inch at the lowest level. The affected area is approximately 8 feet x the width of the house. The house was built in 1979; it's a split level with floor trusses. The dip doesn't appear to be from individual trusses sagging. Rather, it seems the lumber the trusses are fastened to on the exterior wall (top plate?) is sagging. When I hold a board perpendicular to the trusses from the basement, the sag is equally present near the exterior wall as it is further to the interior of the house. My questions are 1. What caused this, and 2. Can it be fixed? Could each truss be jacked up and a good piece of wood inserted between the truss and top plate until the floor becomes level?

When you talk to a pro, the sagging boards (usually 2x8, 2x10 or thereabouts) are joists that are attached to a rim board. Actual trusses are extremely unlikely. You could take a photo and ask another question to clarify if you felt like it.

Jacking up any structural members of a house is not a DIY job. If this settling happened a long time ago, the rest of the house has probably settled with it. If you try to jack it up back in place, you can expect to break all the plaster work just above.
So unless the house is actively sinking, the thing to do is to remove the floor covering (tile, LVP, whatever), add some self-leveler, then install new floor coverings.

Jacking up is also very slow.  OP might be adding months to the job.

Plus, kitchen cabinets complicate the process of jacking.
